# ELKI - Clustering Statistics

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, elki

When a data set is analyzed by a clustering algorithm in ELKI 0.5, the program produces a number of statistics: the Jaccard index, F1-Measures, etc. In order to calculate these statistics, there have to be 2 clusterings to compare. What is the clustering created by the algorithm compared to?

Comment: It is compared to the labels in your data.

Comment: There are no labels in my data, just values. It looks like the resulting clustering is compared to an all-in-one cluster, which makes the statistics misleading. Do you have any idea why there are no internal evaluation metrics, for example the Davies-Bouldin or the Dunn index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *automatic* evaluation (note that you *can* configure the evaluation manually!) is based on labels in your data set. At least in the current version (**why are you using 0.5 and not 0.6.0?**) it should only automatically evaluate *if* it finds labels in the data set.

We currently have not *published* internal measures. There are some implementations, such as [evaluation/clustering/internal/EvaluateSilhouette.java](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/evaluation/clustering/internal/EvaluateSilhouette.java), some of which will be in the next release.

In my experiments, *internal* evaluation measures were badly misleading. For example on the Silhouette coefficient, the labeled "solution" would often even score a negative silhouette coefficient (i.e. worse than not clustering at all).

Also, these measures are not scalable. The silhouette coefficient is in O(n^2) to compute; which usually makes this evaluation more expensive than the actual clustering!

### We do appreciate contributions!

You are more than welcome to contribute your favorite evaluation measure to ELKI, to share with others.

Comment: That makes sense. I am running 0.5 as 0.6 is not available through the Debian stable apt (I noticed you were the author of the package).

As an unsupervised learning technique, clustering should generally work with unlabeled data. Therefore I believe internal measures are crucial to evaluation.

I like the way ELKI is documented and hope I will be able to find some time and contribute!

Comment: ELKI is a Java application, it does not depend on any system library except OpenJDK-7. You can just download the `.jar` file and run it - it does not require installation. The main benefit of the Debian package is that it is slimmer, and shares e.g. Apache Batik with other application, while the download .jar includes a copy of Batik.
I think the only proper ways of evaluating a clustering result are visualization and actually using it. Any statistical evaluation number will be misleading, because it does not test *applicability* to your problem.